# How to write to windows file properties in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, io

I would like to create an attribute and store a value inside of the properties of a file on Windows. You can view such attributes when you write click the file properties>details. How would I create a new att/value here using Ruby?[![enter image description here][1]][1

Comment: IIRC NTFS allows custom properties via ADS (Alternative Data Streams), but haven't thought about that for years. You'd have to use a Windows-specific library to do that.

Comment: I don't know if you can create a *new* attribute.  Can you describe a bit more about what you think the expected outcome would be, regardless of language?

Comment: I have a zip file which, among a bunch of valid xml files, there is a blank file whose name is an md5 hash (that was generated at the creation of this zip). I then have a java program which reads in the content in that zip and calculates a md5 then checks its calculation with the hash that was in the zip. I don't want to have to store the "goal" hash as a file inside of the zip.

Answer (score 2):

Those attributes are specific to a Windows platform, and I am relatively certain there are no mechanisms built-into Ruby to alter them.

This means you will either have to search for a gem that does it for you, or the simpler approach is to simply invoke platform commands to alter them. The `attrib` command is used for changing those, which can be invoked with `system`.

Basic syntax is something like this:

```
attrib [+ attribute | - attribute] [pathname]
```

You **CANNOT** just add any attribute you want, there are specific flags, and they each mean something.

- **R** = Read-only
- **H** = Hidden
- **S** = System
- **D** = Directory
- **A** = Archive
- **C** = Compressed
- **E** = Encrypted
- **N** = Not Indexed
- **L** = Re-parse Points
- **O** = Offline
- **P** = Sparse File
- **I** = Not content indexed
- **T** = Temporary

So, if you wanted to add "hidden" attribute, and remove "read-only" attribute...

```
system 'attrib +H -R myfile.txt'
```

This is likely not a comprehensive list of the flags, but definitely the most common. The point being that you unfortunately cannot just add arbitrary strings, and altering them will have an effect on how the file is handled by Windows.

Comment: Great suggestion. IMO a gem would be total overkill for this. Ruby was heavily inspired by Perl, so using it to glue together existing tools is one of its strong suits!

Comment: "compressed" attribute is not shown for me and is missed in the description `attrib /?`